# Detect Android App Crash and null pointer exceptions at the development time

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

How to detect Android App Crash and null pointer exceptions at the development time with Android studio? Do we have any good static analysis tool? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the application from Android Studio you can check the logcat to see the exception details. If you want to track the crashes even if the device is not connected to Android Studio you can integrate a tool like [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android)

Comment: this doesn't answer what OP is asking, OP is asking for `static analysis tool` to prevent nullpointers from occuring when _developing_ the app, what you're describing here is just how to debug a nullpointer after running the app

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use breakpoint on lines to check null pointer exceptions and by this you can Evaluate Expression during debugging.

[image]

2. You can use Firebase Crashlytics.

build.gradle Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
// add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
// The app need this to init in Firebase console

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'

 // Add the Firebase SDK for Crashlytics.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01'
```

build.gradle Project

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta01'
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all... using breakpoints means that your app is already running...

Comment: if app is crashing on MainActivity then you are right. but can add 1 more screen before MainActiviy like Splash screen. And you can apply brackpoint.

Comment: again, that doesn't help if you have code in your splash screen which can crash...